# Notation in npm solidity-coverage tests

Tags: solidity, truffle, testing

I had been using the `npm` package `solidity-coverage` and while reading the coverage reports I came up with this `E` symbol. I am not sure what it means and there is no explanation in the documentation as well. Does anyone know what this means?

[image]

Comment: Revised the answer several times, so best if you read it as of now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `require(cond, msg)` statement is technically a "shortcut" for:

```
if (cond)
    /* do some stuff */;
else
    revert(msg);
```

Hence an `E` in the solidity-coverage report means that although the `if` case has been covered, the `else` case has not been covered.

In your specific case, the function has been executed only with `to != address(0)`.

In order to cover the other case, you'll need to execute it with `to = address(0)`, for example:

```
try {
    await func("0x0");
    throw null;
}
catch (error) {
    assert(error, "Expected an error but did not get one");
    assert(error.message.startsWith("revert"), "Expected an error starting with 'revert' but got '" + error.message + "' instead");
}
```